# PHP countdown clock errors

Tags: php

I have a PHP countdown clock that I is going to be put on my website but am struggling to debug some errors. When the clock shows 1 minute it still says "1 Minutes" (notice the S in minutes) and it also displays "0 minutes". I have posted a copy of my code below.

```
<?php

countdown(2011,6,7,7,31,0);

function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute){
$the_countdown_date=mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);
$today=time();
$difference=$the_countdown_date - $today;
$days=floor($difference/60/60/24);
$hours=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
$minutes=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/60);
echo "$days days $hours hours $minutes minutes";
}

?>
```

Is there any way I can get it to say "1 minute" and not display the minutes section for "0 minutes"?

I hope people can understand this.
Thanks in advance

Callum

Comment: The correct usage in english IS 0 minutes, not 0 minute, just FYI

Comment: rayman i think you misunderstood something or otherwise had nothing more interesting to say ^^

Comment: No the comment was originally intended for a post that was deleted, so I put it up here for that person to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable that is either "s" or "" depending on the value of the corresponding days/hours/mins:

```
$days_s = $days == 1 ? "" : "s";
$hours_s = $hours == 1 ? "" : "s";
$minutes_s = $minutes == 1 ? "" : "s";
return "$days day$days_s $hours hour$hours_s $minutes minute$minutes_s";
```

Answer (score 0):

add (at top)

```
function nicefmt($n,$s,$trail=" "){
if($n==0) return "";
if($n==1) return "$n $s".$trail;
return "$n ".$s."s".$trail;
}
```

and the replace

```
echo "$days days $hours hours $minutes minutes";
```

with

```
echo nicefmt($days,"day").nicefmt($hours,"hour").nicefmt($minutes,"minute","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put an if statement in that is something like:

```
if ($minutes == 1) {
    echo "$days days $hours hours $minutes minute";
} else if ($minutes == 0) {
    echo "$days days $hours hours";
} else {
  echo "$days days $hours hours $minutes minutes";
}
```

I know this is very verbose... to reduce it, I would the final string into sections and only print the sections needed.

Comment: `$days == 0 && $hours == 0` why?

Comment: I think you meant `!=` not `==`, since the topmost condition (for example) gets executed only when there are 0 days, 0 hours and a minute.

Comment: ..or use the frikkin ternary operator while stealing others' answers.